# Удалить повторяющиеся строки по маске linux

Tags: linux, bash

Существует файл с различными строками
Например:

```
lol
kek
ferrals0
ferrals100
ferrals102
ferrals107
ferrals108
ferrals110
ferrals111
ferrals114
buba6
```

Требуется удалить строки, отчищающиеся только несколькоми символами справа и слева строки и оставить только 1 неизменяемое слово. 
Правильный результат:

```
lol
kek
ferrals
buba6
```

Comment: А что если во входном файле появятся ещё "lir" и "kat"? Оставлять вместо пар lir/lol и kek/kat "l" и "k" соответственно?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Как правило строк с изменяющимися символами "много" (около 10-20 вхождений) а таких как lol и kek 1 штука.

Comment: ferrals107, ferralscuko и ferrals10ferrals — одно и то же? А если есть ferraluminium - сворачивать их все до "ferral"? Если нет, то почему? В общем, критерий "отличающиеся несколькими символами справа и слева", на мой взгляд, требует серьёзного уточнения.

Comment: "несколько" символов это может быть длина всей строки, так для примера.

Comment: Замечание по проверочному тексту, от куда взялась строчка "ferrals"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ясно, что никакого строго алгоритма тут предложить невозможно. Можно попробовать использовать некий вариант алгоритма "развала на кучи" (кластеризации) предложенный  М. Вайнцвайгом и М. Бонгардом в 1973 . Ну, теорию я тут описывать не стану (она не очень простая), но прикинуть реализацию можно.

1. Создаём функцию, вычисляющую разность двух слов. Например, она может работать по такому принципу:

   - Если слова одинаковой длины, то попарно сопоставляем буквы и каждая не совпадающая увеличивает значение разности. Чем ближе сравниваемые буквы к центру слова, тем больше вес их разности.
   - Если слова разной длины, то более короткое "прогоняем" вдоль более более длинного, дополняя пробелами свободную часть. В итоге берём минимальное значение функции разности
2. Для всех слов в списке вычисляем попарные разности.
3. Выполняем собственно развал:

   - Берём случайное слово из начального списка и собираем новый список, куда входят те слова, значения разности с которыми меньше некоторой "дельта".
   - Выбранные слова удаляем из исходного списка
   - Повторяем процесс до тех пор, пока исходный список не опустеет.
4. В каждой куче выбираем самое короткое слово.

Понятно, что на bash такое не написать. Но ведь Вы требуете элементы ИИ, фактически.